# Plotly share datapoint text between subgraphs

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am plotting a graph composed by stacked subplots each with a very high number of points. For each point i would like to add a text to be visualized in the tooltip.

Since the text to be visualized is the same for every sublot I have just passed the same array as `text`attribute of each subgraph (as shown in the Plotly guide).

```
for cluster in sorted(reverse_clustering): 
....         
    trace = go.Scatter(x=base, y=cluster_features, name=name, text=word_list)
```

This, however, seems to be creating a copy of the (very long) array of strings `word_list` in the html file for each subplot.

Is there any way to obtain the same results without having mulitple copy of the same data in the html?

Comment: The data from Python becomes serialized on its way to the Plotly Javascript library. So, no, there is no direct way to share data between graphs.

Comment: Ok seems there is no solution for this, so if you post your comment as an answer i'll mark it as accepted @MaximilianPeters

Comment: The accepted answer was wrong and was updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>*tldr* No, you cannot share data in Plotly.</strike>

Unfortunately there is no way of sharing data between graphs (as far as I know). Plotly's libraries serialize the Python (or R) objects to make them available to its JavaScript core library.

Data sharing would need to happen on the JavaScript and even that is pretty tricky.

You can upload your data as [`grid`](https://plot.ly/python/data-api/#making-graphs-from-grids) objects and then reference them via `xsrc`, `ysrc`, `textsrc`, etc.

```
import plotly
import random

# some random data
data1 = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]
text = ['Measurement: {}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]
data2 = [i + random.random() for i in data]

# create the grid object and its columns
col0 = plotly.grid_objs.Column([i for i in range(10)], 'x')
col1 = plotly.grid_objs.Column(data1, 'exp1')
col2 = plotly.grid_objs.Column(data2, 'exp2')
col3 = plotly.grid_objs.Column(text, 'text')
grid = plotly.grid_objs.Grid([col0, col1, col2, col3])

# upload the grid
plotly.plotly.grid_ops.upload(grid, 'tmp')

# create the graph based on the reference grid columns
trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(xsrc=grid[0], ysrc=grid[1], textsrc=grid[3])
trace2 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(xsrc=grid[0], ysrc=grid[2], textsrc=grid[3])
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2])

plotly.plotly.iplot(fig)
```